# PHP Access JSON Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Can't get json_decode to work here:

```
<?php
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://data.dnr.ne.gov/RealTime/api/6881500/2016/3/8/Discharge' );

$data = json_decode($response);
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th><?php echo $data[0]; ?></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

var_dump($response); spits out the whole json object, so the API call is working fine.

Any help even accessing element 0 will be fantastic!

Comment: what does json_decode() spits out, it would help if you can post that output.

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) returns an std object, you're using it as an array, it won't work. If you want to decode it as an array simply pass `true` as the second parameter to the `json_decode()` function, then you can do `$data[0]`.

Comment: @Andrew: Actually `$data[0]` will still work.  His data is still an array, it's just an array of objects.

Comment: After added the `true` to decode, let's `var_dump($data)` to examine your content of array.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's...actually a very good point.

Comment: @lolka_bolka You could also just put the URL into your browser and see the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar Won't connect for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data[0]` is an object (of type [`stdClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php)). It can be an array if you pass `TRUE` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Either way, [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) cannot display its content. You have to ask it to display the properties (if it's an object) or values (if it's an array) of `$data[0]` to get the information you want.

F.e., using the code you posted, it would be something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Station number</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Value/th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo($row->stationNumber); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo($row->date); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo($row->value); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

If you decode the JSON to arrays (`$data = json_decode($response, TRUE);`), then change the display of the data as follows:

```
<td><?php echo($row['stationNumber']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo($row['date']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo($row['value']); ?></td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`echo` displays its type"?

Comment: If you pass an array to `echo()` it displays `Array` (and triggers a warning). Now I see that if you try to `echo` an object it triggers a fatal error and exits. I removed that part from the answer now.

Comment: `echo` can only display strings.  If you pass it something else, PHP tries to convert that thing into a string.  Converting an array to a string results in the string `"Array"` (and a warning).

Comment: Ok, bueno.  Actually got it to work with:

    $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://data.dnr.ne.gov/RealTime/api/6881500/2016/3/8/Discharge' );
    
    $yummy = json_decode($response['body'], true);
    
    ?>
    
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Station number</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $yummy[2]['date']; ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

Spits out date fine.  Only other q is how to access the last element?  Looking for value for the most recent date.

Comment: The last element and the element with the most recent date are different things if the elements are not already sorted ascending by date. The last element of an array can be retrieved using [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php). If they need to be sorted before that then read about the [array sorting PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) (and use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)). I would also investigate if it's not possible to request the values in descending order and limit the returned elements to one.

Comment: I can't find the facebook thumbs-up button, but thanks!